# Android Studio app for beta testing on Play Store

Tags: android-studio, google-play, beta-testing

What all is required to upload Android Studio app for beta testing on Play Store? Will I need the google developer account, screenshots of the app and detail about the app ?

Answer (score 1):

You will need all the things you listed above and more. Here is a website that can help you with beta testing: [Set up an open, closed, or internal test](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you must need developer account(20$ approx.), screenshot of your app.
Rest of the things like available country, beta testers etc...., will be configured later with your account.